# Generate random number which stays in a variable and then doesn't change

Tags: c#

I am making a console app which shows a random letter and then asks the user to type the letter. The only way I have thought of making this work is by having variables that hold letters which are randomly assigned every time the console app is run. I will then be able to use the variables in IF statements.

I need variables like:

```
firstLetter = letterWhichChangesEverytimeCodeIsRun;
secondLetter = letterWhichChangesEverytimeCodeIsRun;
thirdLetter = letterWhichChangesEverytimeCodeIsRun;
```

I thought of making a random letter generator and then running it inside of a variable, but that just made a random letter every time I called the variable.

Comment: I'd suggest reading up on `Lazy`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store it in a static private variable and only get using a public getter. This is known as [lazy loading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_loading).

```
using System;

public class Program
{       
    private static char? randomLetterM = null;

    public static char RandomLetter
    {
        get
        {
            if (randomLetterM == null)
            {
                Random random = new Random();  
                int index = random.Next(0, 25);  
                randomLetterM = (char) (65 + index);
            }

            return randomLetterM.Value;
        }
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        // Should print 3 same letters per run.
        Console.WriteLine(RandomLetter);
        Console.WriteLine(RandomLetter);
        Console.WriteLine(RandomLetter);
    }
}
```

Comment: How would putting this into variables work if I wanted each variable to be different but never change (until the program is exited and run again)?

Comment: @sbondo1234 Is it a small finite number of them? If so, you could just create that number of properties with it's respective private variable. If it's a large number, you could have an array of characters where the size of the array is how many letters you want and lazily load that. When you lazily load it, just randomly generate each array index.